# How can I read nested objects in a json format and append them to a table as rows

Tags: javascript, html

I have JSON in the format of:

```
[
    {
        id:p1,
        "status": active,
        "main_task": [
            {
                id:m1
                status:active,
                sub_task:[
                    {
                        id:s1.1
                        status: active,
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                id:m2
                status:active,
                sub_task:[
                    {
                        id:s2.1
                        status: active,
                    }
                    {
                        id:s2.2
                        status: active,
                    }
                ]
            },
]
```

I am trying to convert all the name:value pairs into a table row, and the nested ones should be right below the one its nested in(if that makes any sense)

I am trying to implement this with JS but I am unsure on how to proceed, so far I can get all the non-nested name:value pairs as rows, but I am unable to get the nested values as rows.

```
function displayTable(result,id){
               console.log(result)
                console.log("Result:");
                var demo = document.getElementById(id)
                for(var i = 0;i<result.length;i++)
                {
                    var tr = document.createElement('tr')
                    for(const [key,value] of Object.entries(result[i]))
                    {
                        var td = document.createElement('td');
                        td.innerHTML = value;
                        if(key == 'main_task' || key == 'timesheet_details'){
                            td.innerHTML = value
                            displayTable(value[0],)
                        }
                        tr.appendChild(td);
                    }
                    demo.appendChild(tr);

                }
            }
```

Please let me know if the data is insufficient, as I gave a sample of mine( but hopefully it captured the essence)

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>project id</td>
        <td>main_task id</td>
        <td>sub_task id</td>               
        <td>status</td>

    </tr>
</thead>
```

What I am trying get:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>p1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>active</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>m1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>active</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>s1</td>
        <td>active</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @MisterJojo I updatd the code.

Comment: are you expecting some `rowspan` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like that ?

```js
const data = 
  [ { id     : 'p1'
    , status : 'active'
    , main_task: 
      [ { id     : 'm1'
        , status : 'active'
        , sub_task: 
          [ { id: 's1.1', status: 'active'} 
        ] } 
      , { id     : 'm2'
        , status : 'active'
        , sub_task: 
          [ { id: 's2.1', status: 'active'} 
          , { id: 's2.2', status: 'active'} 
  ] } ] } ] 

const t_body = document.querySelector('#my-table tbody')

let nR = null

data.forEach( level_1 =>
  {
  nR = t_body.insertRow()
  nR.insertCell().textContent = level_1.id
  nR.insertCell()
  nR.insertCell()
  nR.insertCell().textContent = level_1.status

  level_1.main_task.forEach( level_2 =>
    {
    nR = t_body.insertRow()
    nR.insertCell()
    nR.insertCell().textContent = level_2.id
    nR.insertCell()
    nR.insertCell().textContent = level_2.status

    level_2.sub_task.forEach( level_3 =>
      {
      nR = t_body.insertRow()
      nR.insertCell() 
      nR.insertCell() 
      nR.insertCell().textContent = level_3.id
      nR.insertCell().textContent = level_3.status
      })
    })
  })
```

```css
table  {
  border-collapse : collapse;
  margin          : 2em 1em;
  font-family  : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size    : 14px;
  }
td,th  {
  padding : .2em .8em;
  border  : 1px solid darkblue;
  }
thead { 
  background : aquamarine;
  }
```

```html
<table id="my-table"> 
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> project  </th>   
      <th> main_task </th>
      <th> sub_task  </th> 
      <th> status  </th> 
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: pretty much that, but without the levels, like each id column should have the appropriate id and status for the related name:value pair.

Comment: how do I do exactly what you did without the levels?

Comment: @ss2 You just want the name:value pair for every single property of every single object in the same two columns, regardless of whether it's nested or not?

Comment: Right, but I can't have the multiple 2nd row where there are multiple id and status columns, they need to be in one column                                                                                     ```<table><tr><td>project ID</td><td>Main ID</td><td>Sub ID</td><td>status</td></tr></table>```

Comment: so lets say for the first two values ```<table><tr><td>p1</td><td></td><td></td><td>active</td></tr><tr><td></td><td>m1</td><td></td><td>active</td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td>s1<td></td><td>active</td></tr></table>```

Comment: yes I would like all status to be in same column

Comment: I updated the code, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @ss2 I have updated my answer; Is that one you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

you might be interested in using rowspan to assemble columns?

```js
const data=[{id:'p1',status:'active',main_task:[{id:'m1',status:'active',sub_task:[{id:'s1.1',status:'active'}]},{id:'m2',status:'active',sub_task:[{id:'s2.1',status:'active'},{id:'s2.2',status:'active'}]}]}]

const t_body = document.querySelector('#my-table tbody')

const tbl =
  { nRow  : null
  , pCell : null
  , pSpan : 1
  , mCell : null
  , mSpan : 1
  }
data.forEach( project =>
  {
  tbl.nRow = t_body.insertRow()
  tbl.pSpan = 1
  tbl.pCell = tbl.nRow.insertCell()
  tbl.pCell.textContent = project.id
  tbl.nRow.insertCell()
  tbl.nRow.insertCell()
  tbl.nRow.insertCell().textContent = project.status

  project.main_task.forEach( mTask =>
    {
    tbl.nRow = t_body.insertRow()
    tbl.pCell.setAttribute('rowspan', ++tbl.pSpan)
    tbl.mSpan = 1
    tbl.mCell = tbl.nRow.insertCell()
    tbl.mCell.textContent = mTask.id
    tbl.nRow.insertCell()
    tbl.nRow.insertCell().textContent = mTask.status

    mTask.sub_task.forEach( sTask =>
      {
      tbl.nRow = t_body.insertRow()
      tbl.pCell.setAttribute('rowspan', ++tbl.pSpan)
      tbl.mCell.setAttribute('rowspan', ++tbl.mSpan)
      tbl.nRow.insertCell().textContent = sTask.id
      tbl.nRow.insertCell().textContent = sTask.status
      })
    })
  })
```

```css
table  {
  border-collapse : collapse;
  margin          : 2em 1em;
  font-family  : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size    : 14px;
  }
td,th  {
  padding        : .2em .8em;
  border         : 1px solid darkblue;
  vertical-align : text-top;
  }
thead { 
  background : aquamarine;
  }
```

```html
<table id="my-table">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>project</th><th>main_task</th><th>sub_task</th><th>status</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```