# Html Table struct for nested categories layout

Tags: css, html-table, nested, categories

I have a table with many categories
Currently, I am rendering them with tr tags, each category will be displayed in a child tag

[image]

But this causes the table layout to break when a parent cell has an increase in height

[image]

`codepend: https://codepen.io/sayuto/pen/YzvPoBO`

Where did I go wrong or does someone have a better idea how to do this?
I have tried rendering a tr tag that will contain "parent" and "first child", "other children" will be rendered in the next tr, but this is very complicated, calculating rowspan is difficult.

I trying to find out the correct html table layout what I should to use to render table with nested categories

P/s: I am trying to render column by column (this makes it easier for us to gather data and load
Building data structures and load data onto tables with default rendering (line by line) is a nightmare for both the writer and the maintainer (in this case - nested categories)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made you this test code...

```js
const
  myTable = document.querySelector('#my-table')
, depIn   = document.querySelector('input[type=range]')
, depInV   = document.querySelector('input[type=range] + span')
  ;
depIn.value = 1;
depInV.textContent = depIn.value + ' X';

depIn.oninput =_=>
  {
  depInV.textContent = depIn.value + ' X'
  myTable.rows[7].cells[0].innerHTML = Array( depIn.valueAsNumber ).fill('x').join('<br>')
  }
```

```css
body {
  font-family      : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size        : 14px;
  }
table {
  border-collapse  : separate;
  border-spacing   : 1px;
  background-color : darkblue;
  margin           : 1em;
  color            : black;
  font-size        : .8rem;
  }
th {
  background-color : lightgrey;
  padding          : .6em;
  min-width        : 3.2em;
  }
td {
  background-color : whitesmoke;
  padding          : .2em .6em;
  min-width        : 3.2em;
  min-height       : 1.5em;
  }
```

```html
<p> any X you need... <br>
  <input type="range" min="1" max="10" value="1"><span>1</span>   
</p>
<table id="my-table">
  <thead> <tr> <th>Compagny</th> <th>Department</th> <th>Group</th> <th>Team</th> <th>Unit</th> </tr> </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="9">.</td> <!-- Compagny      -->
      <td rowspan="3">.</td> <!-- Department L.1 -->
      <td rowspan="2">.</td> <!-- Group      L.1 -->
      <td>.</td>  <!-- Team      L.1 -->
      <td>.</td>  <!-- Unit      L.1 -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>.</td>  <!-- Team      L.2 -->
      <td>.</td>  <!-- Unit      L.2 -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>.</td> <!-- Group      L.2 -->
      <td>.</td>  <!-- Team      L.3 -->
      <td>.</td>  <!-- Unit      L.3 -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">.</td> <!-- Department L.2 -->
      <td>.</td> <!-- Group      L.3 -->
      <td>.</td>  <!-- Team      L.4 -->
      <td>.</td>  <!-- Unit      L.4 -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">.</td> <!-- Group      L.4 -->
      <td>.</td>  <!-- Team      L.5 -->
      <td>.</td>  <!-- Unit      L.5 -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>.</td>  <!-- Team      L.6 -->
      <td>.</td>  <!-- Unit      L.6 -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3"> x </td> <!-- Department L.3 -->
      <td>.</td> <!-- Group      L.5 -->
      <td>.</td>  <!-- Team      L.7 -->
      <td>.</td>  <!-- Unit      L.7 -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">.</td> <!-- Group      L.6 -->
      <td>.</td>  <!-- Team      L.8 -->
      <td>.</td>  <!-- Unit      L.8 -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>.</td>  <!-- Team      L.9 -->
      <td>.</td>  <!-- Unit      L.9 -->
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply.
as I say above, I am trying to render column by column (this makes it easier for us to gather data and load)

in you example, it is a default layout, it good, but very hard to collect data and load data onto, logic will be very complex

Comment: @Sayuto No, I don't find it really complex, you just have to know how to count the lines. I have already made a table loader from JSON data on a similar model, there is nothing complicated.

Comment: @Sayuto  see there : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68552946/how-can-i-read-nested-objects-in-a-json-format-and-append-them-to-a-table-as-row/68553773#68553773

Comment: I'm not sure about the logic or the structure you used. but I have found there are many problems to solve if I want to render the table row by row: rowspan, number of td tags, find data for current cell and how to structure json data. in the first line you can render all of them easily, but from the second line, there will be many possible cases: there is a parent tag / there is a child tag / there is a grandchild tag /....

Comment: thank you, as I understand, that logic is good but it is good for static columns. in my case, everything is dynamic, cells, columns, and rows also can be change

Comment: @Sayuto  I also done this one, whitch is dynamic to but it's a bit different...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59942996/how-to-add-sub-row-in-table-on-button-click/59944121#59944121

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. We decided to use div instead of table to keep the logic simple to make it easier to maintain later. anyway thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

The trick with tables that have lots of `rowspan`s and `colspan`s is to count the cells and disregard the styling.

You can see in the first image you have 9 rows in the tbody. And the first cell spans all of them. So your first cell must be `<td rowspan="9">`. Carrying on, the remainder of the first row has `<td rowspan="3"><td rowspan="2"><td><td>`.

The second row already has the first 3 columns "used up", so that's just `<td><td>`

If you carry on in that vein, you'll construct a table that behaves robustly.

Comment: thank you for your reply. 
I get it, you're talking about rendering line by line. (default way) 

I am trying to render column by column (this makes it easier for us to gather data and load)
Building data structures and load data onto tables with default rendering (line by line) is a nightmare for both the writer and the maintainer (in this case)